# Do I have to wait until In-App purchase gets reviewed to be able to test it?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have created, added (at version details), and clicked ready for upload a new In-App item along a new version, but product detail request still **returns it as invalid**.

What to do? How long does it take until it gets review-d?

When will I ever be able to test In-App purchases? Grrrrhhhg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test InApp purchases Here is a good detailed flow of how to go about it

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

Answer (score 0):

No.

Just don`t forget to add it to the latest version of your App at Version details page, before set "Ready to upload".